# Escaping Double Quotations in Python F-String Literal

Tags: python, f-string

When attempting to escape double quotation marks in a f-string literal in Python, I encounter a strange phenomenon where subsequent single quotes are automatically escaped. This is not what I want, as I intend to pass the "query" string as a SQL Server query which does not process the forward slash as an escape character, but rather as part of the query.

```
query = f"select apples,\
bananas,\
cranberries,\
durian \
from schema.\"database_name/table_name\" \
where SNAPSHOT_PERIOD = '123' and parameter IN('abc') \
group by POB_ID"

print(query)
```

Per debugger, resulting string:

```
'select apples,bananas,cranberries,durian from schema."database_name/table_name" where SNAPSHOT_PERIOD = \'123\' and parameter IN(\'abc\')'
```

Desired result:

```
'select apples,bananas,cranberries,durian from schema."database_name/table_name" where SNAPSHOT_PERIOD = '123' and parameter IN('abc')'
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the difference between a string's contents and its `repr`. The ``\'`` sequences in the first string are not actual backslashes. Those are just there to make the repr'd string look like a valid string literal.

Comment: What do you mean "Per debugger"? The output of the `print` statement? The string doesn't have a leading `'` ... where does that come from? The desired result isn't a valid python literal, the whole single quotes in single quotes just seems wrong.

Comment: You could also just use a triple quoted string and not escape the quotes. Also, using f-strings implies, that you're going to insert values into them. This can be very dangerous. Most Python database modules allow the use of [prepared statements](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#paramstyle), maybe you should check those out to not learn bad habits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing `\'` in your final string is because Python produces the `repr` of a `str` in the following way:

- If the string contains neither quotes, encode it in single quotes
- If the string contains single quotes but not double quotes, enclose it in double quotes
- If the string contains double quotes but not single quotes, enclose it in single quotes.
- If the string contains both quotes, enclose it in single quotes, escaping any single quotes present. This is the case you're seeing.

This way, the `repr` is always a valid string literal that when evaluated will produce the original string's content, regardless of the actual content. If the quotes weren't escaped, they would mark the start/end of new string literals, meaning that `repr` wouldn't function as intended.

The above processes are totally visual, and your code is functioning as intended - it's just a product of the way the debugger displays the `repr` of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is perfectly fine:

```
In [1]: query = f"select apples,\
...: bananas,\
...: cranberries,\
...: durian \
...: from schema.\"database_name/table_name\" \
...: where SNAPSHOT_PERIOD = '123' and parameter IN('abc') \
...: group by POB_ID"
...: 
...: print(query)
select apples,bananas,cranberries,durian from schema."database_name/table_name" where SNAPSHOT_PERIOD = '123' and parameter IN('abc') group by POB_ID
```

But the debugger seems to be showing you the `__repr__` of query:

```
In [2]: query.__repr__()
Out[2]: '\'select apples,bananas,cranberries,durian from schema."database_name/table_name" where SNAPSHOT_PERIOD = \\\'123\\\' and parameter IN(\\\'abc\\\') group by POB_ID\''
```

Here is a more detailed tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-str-repr-functions in case you want to understand better the difference between `str` and `repr`